# Calculo usando campos preenchidos jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho os seguintes campos:

```
moeda, taxa_compra, taxa_venda, valor_reais, valor_total
```

Preciso que, ao preencher taxa de venda, calcule:

```
taxa_venda / valor_reais e represente o total no valor_total.
```

Como eu posso montar um jquery para fazer isso?

Comment: o que você tentou até agora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Como eu posso montar um jquery para fazer isso?

Você pode usar um *event handler* do tipo `input` ou `blur`, por exemplo:

```
$("seletor_do_campo_taxa_de_venda").on("input ou blur", function(){
   // ação
});
```

O `input` irá executar *ação* à medida em que algum valor é inserido ou removido do campo; o `blur` quando o campo perde o *focus* (o cursor sai do campo).

Para realizar a divisão *taxa_venda / valor_reais* é preciso que os valores de ambos os campos sejam do tipo `number`. Caso os campos sejam do tipo `text`, é preciso convertê-los para `number`.

Para jogar o valor no campo *valor_total*, coloque em *ação* o resultado da divisão:

```
// se os campos forem tipo number
$("seletor_do_campo_taxa_de_denda").on("input ou blur", function(){
   var total = $("seletor_do_campo_taxa_de_venda").val() / $("seletor_do_campo_valor_total").val();
   $("seletor_do_campo_valor_total").val(total);
});
```

ou

```
// se os campos forem tipo text com decimais separados por vírgula
$("seletor_do_campo_taxa_de_venda").on("input ou blur", function(){
    var tx_venda = parseFloat($("seletor_do_campo_taxa_de_venda").val().replace(".","").replace(",","."));
    var vl_total = parseFloat($("seletor_do_campo_valor_total").val().replace(".","").replace(",","."));
    var total = tx_venda / vl_total;
    $("seletor_do_campo_valor_total").val(total);
});
```

**Obs.:** caso o elemento que representa o *valor_total* seja uma `div`, troque `$("seletor_do_campo_valor_total").val(total);` por `$("seletor_do_campo_valor_total").text(total);`

Comment: Muito bom, era isso mesmo!